# Angularjs promise wait for result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs app I have the following code on button click:

```
 if (!$scope.isChecked) {
    $scope.getExistingName($scope.userName).then(function (data) {  
        $scope.userName = data;    
    });
  }

  //some processing code here then another promise  

 myService.save($scope.userName,otherparams).then(function (res) {
       //route to page
    }, function (err) {
 });
```

The issue here is if $scope.isChecked is false, it goes inside the promise and since it takes time to resolve it comes out and goes to next line of code. Because of this $scope.userName is not updated and uses old values instead of the updated value returned.

Whats the best way to handle this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.  Is it that `$scope.userName = data;` never happens?  If so, I would set a break point on that line to see if it ever gets hit, and what the value of `data` is.

Comment: It goes inside the loop but then goes to the next line of code without updating the userName as it still waiting for the promise to resolve. So when I actually use the userName I get the old value instead of newer one returned from the promise.

Comment: Just move `myService.save()` code block inside of the `.then()`, just below `$scope.userName = data;` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$q`. First you have to inject `$q` in your angular controller.

```
 //Create empty promise
 var promise;

 if (!$scope.isChecked) {
   promise = $scope.getExistingName($scope.userName).then(function (data) {  
        $scope.userName = data;    
    });
  }

 // Wait or not for your promise result, depending if promise is undefined or not.
 $q.all([promise]).then(function () {

  //some processing code here then another promise  

  myService.save($scope.userName,otherparams).then(function (res) {
        //route to page
     }, function (err) {
  });
});
```

Comment: Will try this and let you know.

Comment: Good, to more information you can see this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 1):

If the myService.save need to wait for the $scope.getExistingName promise just compute that operation inside the "then" statement.

```js
 if (!$scope.isChecked) {
    $scope.getExistingName($scope.userName).then(function (data) {  
         $scope.userName = data;    
         myService.save($scope.userName,otherparams).then(function (res) {
             //route to page
         }, function (err) {
         });
    });
  }

  //some processing code here then another promise
```